# How to open an endpoint to everyone?

Tags: java, angular, api, security, oauth-2.0

I am implementing OAuth2 in my App. The problem is that I want to open some endpoints to make them accessible without any authentication or role. The file that is giving problems is this: (I want to open an endpoint that is "/api/someRoute/parameters")

````
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/someRoute/parameters").permitAll()
```